# How to give the encoded output of an encoder to the inputs of a classifier?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, classification, autoencoder

I am trying to use an `AutoEncoder` to enhance the performance of a classifier.

This is the `AutoEncoder` I wrote using the keras documentation for MNIST data:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# this is the size of our encoded representations
# 32 floats -> compression of factor 24.5, assuming the input is 784 floats
encoding_dim = 32

# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Now I'm trying to connect it to a classifier. Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565638/how-to-initialise-weights-of-a-mlp-using-an-autoencoder-2nd-part-deep-autoenc), I wrote:

```
x = encoder.output
# h = Dense(3, activation='relu', name='hidden')(x)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)

classifier = Model(inputs=autoencoder.inputs, outputs=y)


# Compile model
classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
history = classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                         epochs=10, 
                         batch_size=10,
                         validation_split=.1)
```

First, I don't understand this code. Second, I guess the output of `y` must be 10 corresponding of 10 digits, but I can't set it to 10 because I get an error.

Anyway, the accuracy of the above classifier is very low (10%)! Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: Your model has one layer, with very few parameters. The question is, why should you get good results in the first place?